# What is the difference between a population and a data set?

Tags: statistics

A data set is defined as a collection of data, while a population is defined as a collection of items under consideration.

What is the main  difference between a data set and a population?

I have been seeing these two terms being used interchangeablely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A population in statistics is a set of individuals, companies, etc, on which we'd like to draw inference. For example, if we want to make inference about the proportion of HIV positive American citizens, then American citizens is our population. For obvious reasons, we cannot sample the entire population. Thus, we use a subset of our population and use some sort of sample. When the sampling procedure is done, the data is usually collected in a data set, which we use to make analyses in for instance R, Excel, EViews, and so on.